# Windows 10 java gui jframe over bound

Tags: java, user-interface, jframe

I have some issue in Java GUI.

this is my original code

```
public class GUI extends JFrame{

public GUI(){

}

public static void main(String[] args){
    GUI gui = new GUI();
    gui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    gui.setSize(500, 400);
    gui.setVisible(true);
    gui.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    gui.setLocation(dim.width / 2 - gui.getSize().width / 2, dim.height / 2 - gui.getSize().height / 2);


}

}
```

and this is result

[JFrame Over Bound](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oBSw2.png)

My OS is windows 10.

Could it be a problem?

Could someone please tell me how to solve this?

[another pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X095I.png)

the problem is size of title bar and contents is different.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm struggling to see the problem?

Comment: you should not modify anything about a window in the main thread after calling setVisible(true); Once the gui thread has started all modifications must be on the swing thread

Comment: @MeBigFatGuy: If OK, I'm adding the important Swing event thread info to my community wiki answer.

Comment: @SteveSmith I adding the pic.

Answer (score 1):

Always call `setVisible(true)` **last** and always pack your GUI. For example:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class GUI extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            GUI gui = new GUI();
            gui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            gui.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 400));
            gui.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            gui.pack();
            gui.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            gui.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
```

and incorporating MeBigFatGuy's important recommendation: remember to always create the GUI on the Swing event thread.

Comment: Thanks for helping.